# Determine PNG transperent area in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, png, transparency

I have a png image with an object on transperent background.
This is shown in a browser.

When user hovers PNG image, there is a hover event in javascript.
Is it possible to determine if mouse pointer is over transparent area of the PNG image or not?

Answer (score 1):

In the canvas-enabled browsers yes. You can [draw your image](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage) on the canvas and then [get the color and transparence](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-getimagedata) of the certain pixel.

Comment: Can I draw multiple PNG images on canvas and determine which one of them is hovered(ignoring transparent area of each one)?